# What is happening when a python class is instantiated but it does not have any __init__() method defined?

Tags: python, constructor

Given the following class declaration:

```
class FactorizationModel(ModelWrapper, Saveable, Loader):
```

in which *ModelWrapper*, *Saveable*, and *Loader* are other base classes of *FactorizationModel*

This class does **not have any __init__ method** defined. Instead it has a few def's including

```
def predict(self, user, product):

def predictAll(self, user_product):

def userFeatures(self):

def productFeatures(self):
```

Given there is no **init** method: please explain what is happening in the following invocation of a constructor.

From some client code that imports this class:

```
    return FactorizationModel(model)
```

**Update** OK the first answer here is correct. Adding relevant info to make this clear:

```
class ModelWrapper(object):
    # the following base class constructor is getting called implicitly..
    def __init__(self, model):
          ...
```

Comment: @MalikBrahimi updated the OP and fixed the incorrect class name.

Comment: It inherits `__init__` the same way it would inherit any other method (which can be kind of complicated in a multiple inheritance situation).

Comment: For more on the Method Resolution Order (mro) see http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializer is inherited from a parent class, problem solved. It's sort of messed up in multiple inheritance, it will only use the first passed super class if there is a conflict. For example:

```
class C(A, B): # initializer from A will be used
class C(B, A): # initializer from B will be used
```

Comment: There are three base classes. Does it go to the first one of them that has a compatible __init__() method?

Answer (score 0):

All classes in Python inherits from a base class called Object which allocate that class into memory(now it's called Object; an instance of a class.) Thus those classes that doesn't have initializer call the base class initializer